# Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member ‘uid’

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to access a user's uid in Firebase Authentication. I created a createUser completion block in my code and at the end of the block I want to check for the user in which I named firUser. When I try to add `firUser.uid` in my User I get the error message

> "Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member ‘uid’"

Below is a copy of the code I wrote hopefully some one can help me.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (firUser, error) in
  if error != nil {
     // report error
  } else if let firUser = firUser {
    let newUser = User(uid: firUser.uid, username: username, fullName: fullName, bio: "", website: "", follows: [], followedBy: [], profileImage: self.profileImage)
    newUser.save(completion: { (error) in
      if error != nil {
        // report
      } else {
        // Login User
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (firUser, error) in
          if let error = error {
           // report error
           print(error)
         } else {
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password_based_account), when using `.createUser`,

> If the new account was successfully created, the user is signed in,
>   and you can get the user's account data from the result object that's
>   passed to the callback method.

Notice in the sample, you get back `authResult`, not a User object. `authResult` contains some information, including the User. You can get to the User using `authResult.user`.

In addition, when calling the method, if successful, the user is already signed in, so there's no reason to sign them in again. I changed the parameter name to `authResult` from the sample to help eliminate some of the confusion.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { authResult, error in
  if let error = error {
     // report error
     return
  } 
  guard let authResult = authResult else { return }
  let firUser = authResult.user
  let newUser = User(uid: firUser.uid, username: username, fullName: fullName, bio: "", website: "", follows: [], followedBy: [], profileImage: self.profileImage)
  newUser.save(completion: { (error) in
    if let error = error {
      // report
    } else {
      // not sure what you need to do here anymore since the user is already signed in
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: The code works the project now compiles without any error.

Comment: When you say it does not seem to work, what do you mean? I just tested and it works for me. Keep in mind that the code from `newUser` and below is just functions that this developer wrote. If you're looking for a way to update a user, you can find out how by checking the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).