# Wait before calling a function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firestore for my iOS app project and I would like to add some additional data to the user, so I created a collection called "profiles" where I'd like each document named as the `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid` so I can retrieve the data later for each user (or is there a better way?).

These documents in Firestore are created when the user register a new account:

```
func createUser() {
    db.collection("profiles").document("\(currentUser?.uid)").setData([
        "name": name,
        "surname": surname,
        "email": email,
        "shelter": isMember == true ? shelters[selectedShelter] : shelters[0],
        "photoURL": imageURL ?? "",
        "reputation": 0,
        "uuid": "\(uuid)"
    ])
    { err in
        if let error = err {
            print("Error ading document: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Document added")
        }
    }
}
```

But, at the moment this function is called *(when clicking on the "Register" button)*, the `currentUser` doesn't exist as it is defined to `Auth.auth().currentUser`, so the `currentUser.uid` = nil in my "profiles" documents in Firestore.

The function createUser is called in my Register function:

```
func register() {
    if self.email != ""  {
        if self.pass == self.repass {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                    self.alert.toggle()
                    return
                }
                // Success registering a new user
                viewRouter.currentView = "Home"
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.createUser()
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            self.error = "Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas"
            self.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
    else {
        self.error = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs"
        self.alert.toggle()
    }
}
```

I thought about waiting that `Auth.auth().currentUser` exists before calling the createUser function. I tried using `DispatchQueue.main.async` without success.

Any idea? Or maybe a better way to achieve my goal - which is to add more data to each user (e.g. : reputation, shelter,...)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry I misexplained myself, what I want is to call createUser "after" the Auth.auth().currentUser exists, not doing something after createUser is called. I've updated the main post.

Comment: Well then, your code looks great. You are calling `self.createUser` in the completion handler of `Auth.auth().createUser`.

Comment: Remove `DispatchQueue.main.async {` as it's not needed. Other than that, your code is fine. Once a Firebase user is created, it's automatically logged in and you have access to that user object in that function directly or in `self.createUser()` so.... what's the problem? See [access user info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). Oh, there's a great answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409307/value-of-type-authdataresult-has-no-member-uid) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, and you can actually get that newly-created user using the `res` parameter in your completion handler.

Example

```swift
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
    if err != nil {
        self.error = err!.localizedDescription
        self.alert.toggle()
        return
    }

    // Successfully registered a new user, get the user id
    guard let currUserId = res?.user.uid else { return }

    // ...

    // Maybe add uid as a parameter of createUser
    createUser(id: currUserId)
}
```